# Create HTML5 Canvas programmatically

Tags: html, canvas

I have the following HTML code snippets

```
<body onload="main()" >
    ...
    <canvas id="myId" class="myClass"></canvas>
    ...
</body>
```

It works as expected. I can display the output correctly.

I then remove

```
<canvas id="myId" class="myClass"></canvas>
```

Because I want to create it programmatically with the following JavaScript code snippet

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.className  = "myClass";
canvas.id = "myId";
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work. I cannot display anything with this.

I am wondering if I miss something. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to actually attach the canvas to the document. Before you do so, it's just a detached element that the browser does not render.

```
var canvas = /* ... */;
/* ... */
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(canvas);
```

Comment: @Ben, @Matt -- Both solutions work. Voted for both of them already. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @pion: you're welcome. I just noticed that our answers were posted within 1 second of each other...

Answer (score 26):

You need to insert the new `<canvas>` element into the DOM. To put it at the end of the body, use:

```
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

with the code that creates it. (If you want to put it inside a different element, use that instead of `document.body`.)